# Does container size depend from size of docker volume?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, swarm

I run the following docker image:

```
docker run -d -v home/myap:/home/node/appl example1 :latest
```

Let's assume that we run container `example1` and it writes extensively into /home/node/app directory (1 GB every 1 minute). So in 10 minutes, we have written 10 GB.

If the docker container wasn't restarted am I right that size of the directory `home/myapp` as well as the size of docker container `/home/node/app` will be 10GB? So did our write operation take in total 20 GB of space?

Is there a way to keep the size inside of a docker container restricted, for example, no more than 3GB? Would Swarm or K8s help us with that?

Comment: In Kubernetes you can generally control the size of mounted volumes, and "ephemeral storage" (container filesystem size) can have resource limits applied to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Am I right that size of the directory home/myapp as well as the size of docker container /home/node/app will be 10GB?

No, you are not. Your `home/myapp` directory will be mounted into the container – so instead of writing into the container, it will write into your `home/myapp` directory.

However, *from the container's perspective*, `/home/node/app` will be 10Gi in size – and say so if you jump into the container and have a look.

This follows UNIX mechanics, where you have a virtual file system, and storage mediums are mounted to different paths inside this virtual file system. In your case, said storage medium is the file path `home/myapp`, which is mounted to `/home/node/app`.